# Swift Playground and Simulator Error (ipc/mig) server died, Unable to boot the iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, simulator, swift, xcode6

When I try to do anything in Playground, this pops up before I even finish typing a word.

Error running playground.
Failed to launch iOS stub for playground: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Mach error -308 - (ipc/mig) server died).

and when I just try to run IOS Simulator I get the following error

Unable to boot the iOS Simulator.

oh and this error just popped up

An error was encountered while running (Domain = DTiPhoneSimulatorErrorDomain, Code = 2)

I tried rebooting, I closed out and opened again, I deselected file and reselected. Just keeps happening. Anyone have a solution?

Comment: an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/24042126/1589731

Comment: that answer didn't work for me, but thanks.

Comment: I was trying to install iOS(iPadOS...) 13.x onto iPad Air 4th gen simulator and got this error. Realized that the device was launched with iPadOS 14, so putting any lower version than that was a mistake. The one stop shop to check iOS device specs like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_and_iPadOS_devices

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your firewall is blocking the debugger, you need to allow it to connect:

`TCP out 127.0.0.1:63748`

Or allow the `debugserver` process open access (whichever you, or your firewall, prefer(s)).

Upon enabling it, and restarting Xcode everything should work like a charm.

Note/Update:

If you're having trouble finding, or allowing, the `debugserver` simply try, temporarily, disabling your firewall and restart xcode. Does the playground work? Oh, and don't forget to make sure you've got the assistant view open and the output box showing.

Comment: I am really hoping that is it. My firewall has Allow for Xcode, Xcode beta 6, and even iOS simulator, still doesn't work. I tried searching for debug server and can't find it. I apologize, this must really show how green I am.

Comment: What firewall software are you using? If it shows processes as they try to connect, leave the window open (because the debug server crashes quickly) then open xcode. Try to use the playground-- then go check the firewall. Hopefully you can see where the process tried to connection and allow it. Then restart xcode. If you let me know what firewall you're using, I'll see if I can find you better instructions. Or maybe even just test it, try disabling the firewall completely? That way you'll know for sure if it's the source of the problem or not.

Comment: Just the generic Firewall that comes with Imac. System Preferences->Privacy Security ->Firewall. However I turned it off and it still had the same problem. I opened up an old file written in Objective C only and it compiled and opened Simulator just fine. So something is wrong in my setup. I have the Swift Ibook and I don't see any special instructions about setting up the storyboard, but I must be missing something..

Comment: In my case I was on a corporate network. Once I connected to my "personal hotspot", the simulator works just fine!

Answer (score 1):

Currently the Xcode 6 beta needs to reside in \Applications for the playground and simulator to work. After you move it there you need to reboot.

Answer (score 0):

This error popped up for me when I **closed the simulator** before Xcode finished attaching my application to it. Opening the simulator and running the app again solved this problem.