# Error while running my first IOS app on Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I just created my new iOS project as a single view app and tried running it with no codes added, but there appears just a blank black window in the iOS simulator, and it generates the below error:

> "The operation couldn't be completed. (Mach error -308 -(ipc/mig)server died)"

Comment: Post your code, screenshot and error messages here.. This will help to get your problem solved soon

Comment: What is your question, what have you tried to do?

Comment: @SujalDhungana try to clean the build and then try.

Comment: @Markus  i didn't tried anything just created a single view app and run it but it generated that popup msg and just a blank window of ios simulator appears.

Comment: @AshokLondhe that didn't help

Comment: @SujalDhungana change your schema name . then clean the code and run

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this question:

[Swift Playground and Simulator Error (ipc/mig) server died, Unable to boot the iOS Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028635/swift-playground-and-simulator-error-ipc-mig-server-died-unable-to-boot-the-i?rq=1)

Hopefully that will help you too.