# iOS Simulator won't work and xCode builds app way too slow

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, build, ios-simulator

Can somebody explain these two error messages when building an app on xCode? I am using swift on xCode 6.3.2 and it takes like 3 minutes to build a fairly simple, single-view app. And when it opens on the iOS simulator, I just see a black screen.

xCode says "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Mach error -308 - (ipc/mig) server died)" and "Exception encountered connecting to CoreSimulatorBridge: connection went invalid while waiting for a reply."

I looked at this [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028635/swift-playground-and-simulator-error-ipc-mig-server-died-unable-to-boot-the-i?rq=1), but disabling the firewall and restarting xCode did not fix my problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: That sounds like something is very wrong. I don't know what, but what you describe is not normal. Have you tried restarting your Mac? Have you tried deleting and reinstalling Xcode?

Comment: Try deleting the derived data, you can see how here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933321/deleting-contents-from-xcode-derived-data-folder

Answer (score 0):

The error messages you are reporting indicate that the simulated device was shutdown while Xcode was trying to communicate to it.  This is usually caused by quitting Simulator.app (or iOS Simulator.app as it was called prior to Xcode 7).