# Xcode 8 won't run my application

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, compiler-errors, xcode8

I'm trying to run a sample app; its source can be found here: https://github.com/bandwidthcom/catapult-reference-app-voice-ios

In commit `c669271`, before the app was migrated to Xcode 8 and Swift 3, I was able to run it in devices from Xcode 7 - the Simulator wasn't working since one of its dependencies wasn't built for x86_64.

But since it was updated, when I try to run the application on a Simulator from Xcode 8, I get the following error:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (Mach error -308 - (ipc/mig) server died)

There's a similar error when running on a device, but since I don't have one with me right now, I'll edit this question with further details tomorrow.

I saw it working thrice. The only thing that comes to mind is that I had a clean install of Xcode each time it worked. After something like a reboot, or just a restart of Xcode, I wasn't able to run it anymore.

I don't have a firewall enabled, so the accepted answer to this question ([Swift Playground and Simulator Error (ipc/mig) server died, Unable to boot the iOS Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24028635/4909026)) doesn't solve my problem.

Any ideas?

*OBS: You have to edit the Config.swift file to be able to build the project: any value in the place of `"<replace me>"` will suffice.*

Comment: Have you tried cleaning caches? Ctrl+Shift+K followed by Ctrl+Option+Command+K (the latter cleans the build folder).

Comment: I didn't know the second keyboard shortcut, but it didn't fix the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem was related to a framework that was being embedded in the application via symlink.

I changed one of the build scripts to copy the framework and now everything is working as expected.

Not sure why it worked before, but that seems to be the answer!