# Xcode simulator stuck "Launching Simulator" and gets freezes loading in an Xcode project

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, macos, simulator

Around 6 years ago I begun using Xcode on my MacBook Pro Mid 2010 2.4GHZ 4GB Ram.

I stopped after 12 months or so and now want to try start up again.

I'd deleted Xcode from Applications and decided to install a fresh copy.

Upon opening Playground it gets stuck on "Launching Simulator".

I decided to leave that and decided to get going with a new project.

When I build an empty project the simulator appears after a minute or two with the apple logo and progress bar. It gets to 80% each time and freezes. I quit and this message appears:

"The operation couldn't be completed. (Mach error - 308 - (pic/mig) server died)."

I've tried reset content and setting.
Force quit.
Uninstalled Xcode.
Moved Xcode to documents and then back to Applications.
Turning firewall off.

I best add that the MacBook is running very slow and has been doing over the past 12 months or so. I've considered upgrading the RAM to 8GB.

Does anyone have a fix? I've spent hours and hours and i'm getting nowhere.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028635/swift-playground-and-simulator-error-ipc-mig-server-died-unable-to-boot-the-i?rq=1

Comment: Thanks you. But how do I "Your firewall is blocking the debugger, you need to allow it to connect:

TCP out 127.0.0.1:63748

Or allow the debugserver process open access "

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

I first formatted my hard drive and clean installed OS however this didn't do much.
I then updated my RAM from 4GB to 8GB, this didn't do an awful lot either with regards to Xcode - Laptop did speed up slightly however.

Upgraded to an SSD from standard hard drive - WOW. This fixed the issue with Xcode totally, it's now running like a dream. The SSD upgrade made a massive difference, way more than upgrading the RAM.